# Set the same height of a ReactJS Component to a div

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a dashboard view on my application and it has some graphs. When I have the data to be shown in the graph I am rendering it, otherwise I am just showing a message that says that no information for that component is available.
 However, when I render the message the IboxContent doesn't have the same height as the other IboxContent, and in order to have a better view I wanted to show them both with the same height, even though one of them (graph) is not being shown.

[Screenshot showing both Iboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAjv8.png)

Component that it's being rendered:

```
<div class="row">
  <div className="col-sm-6">
    <Ibox>
      <IboxTitle>
        <h3 className="hfc-green">Entradas</h3>
      </IboxTitle>
      <IboxContent>
        <Chart data={checkins} type="doughnut"/>
      </IboxContent>
    </Ibox>
  </div>
  <div className="col-sm-6">
    <Ibox>
      <IboxTitle>
        <h3 className="hfc-green">Saídas</h3>
      </IboxTitle>
      <IboxContent>
        <Chart data={checkouts} type="doughnut"/>
      </IboxContent>
    </Ibox>
  </div>
</div>
```

Chart Component:

```
const Chart = ({ data, type }) => {
  if (!type || !data)
    return <div>Não há informações sobre este componente no momento </div>

const Component = ChartJsComponents[
  type[0].toUpperCase() +
  type.slice(1)
];

return (
  <Component
    data={data}
    options={chartOptions}
  />
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to do what you want.

Change your `<div class="row">` with `<div class="row" style={{display: "flex"}}>` (implicite `alignItems: "stretch"`) and both of your 2 `<div className="col-sm-6">` will have the same height, whatever the Chart is display or not.

Comment: sorry, but where should I implicite alignItems: "stretch"?

Comment: `stretch` is the default value of `alignItems`. You don't need to add `alignItems: "stretch"`, it's just a comment. Otherwise, it's a css property, so it come in the `style` property

Comment: Actually it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions to solve it? :-/

Comment: You can check if [bootstrap card-layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-layout) works

Comment: thank you! the previous one worked. I had some errors outside that code I posted.